# Unfold a 3D non-linear surface into a 2D array

Tags: python, algorithm, stretching, manifold

I have an isosurface of a 3D field which I would like to project on a 2D map, basically like stretching an elastic bumpy surface so that it becomes flat. I've been using various dimensionality reduction methods using for instance the ones in sklearn (https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/manifold/plot_compare_methods.html#example-manifold-plot-compare-methods-py), but the results aren't satisfactory... my surface is more convoluted since it is an isosurface.

Somehow since we're only talking about going from 3 to 2 dimensions, I wonder if there is an easier way than using those methods that are usually used for high-dimensionality sets. Isn't there a way to basically do what you would do with a real surface ? (stretch the elastic surface with your hands until it is flat)